# Errors while sending XML payload using the app router, NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, app-router

I am getting a `internal server error: 500` when trying to call an external API using the route handler in NextJS 13.

Router handler code, `/app/api/nab/route.ts`:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const xmlPayload = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NABTransactMessage>
<MessageInfo>
...
</Payment>
</NABTransactMessage>`;

  try {
    await fetch("https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/xmlapi/payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/xml" },
      body: xmlPayload,
    });
    res.status(200);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to send XML request a");
  }
}
```

At the API is called via the app router with the function below in a client component, `/app/test/page`:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: {
    currentTarget: HTMLFormElement | undefined;
    preventDefault: () => void;
  }) => {try {
    const response = await fetch("/api/nab", {
      method: "POST"
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Something went wrong! Status: ${response.text}`);
    }

    const responseData = await response.text();
    console.log(responseData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

The XML API interface is provided by NAB so its something that I cant change. I have tried the same **configuration** in Postman and it works fine. For convenience and testing, I am even just adding the test XML payload direct in my route handler but I am returned the same error every time.

Is there something I am missing? If it is worth noting, I have made several changes but I am either hitting 405s or errors with the CORS policy, the latter which I am not that worried about as long as I am able to configure the headers.

---

**Update**
It works fine with the following changes in the route handler:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export interface NextApiTextRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  text: () => Promise<string>;
}

export async function POST(req: NextApiTextRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    const body = await req.text()

    const response = await fetch("https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/xmlapi/payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/xml" },
      body: body,
    });

    console.log(response.ok)

    return response

}
```

Ignoring that the request body is now received from the component, removing the `res.status(200)` removes the error. Without much testing, I am guessing that the handler needs to be ended with `.end()` or with most of the examples, send a body with `.send` or `.json`.